# Segfault from fread()/calloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fread, calloc

I'm not sure why I running this (with argv[1] being a ppm image) is causing a segfault. Any thoughts?

```
unsigned char *image;
char *name;
int sz;

name = argv[1];
FILE *fpt;

fpt = fopen(name,"rb");

fseek(fpt, 0, SEEK_END);
sz = ftell(fpt);
fseek(fpt, 0, SEEK_SET);

image = (unsigned char *) calloc(sz, 1);
fread(image, 1, sz, fpt);
```

Comment: On which line does it segfault? Did you verify that fopen() succeeded and did not return NULL? Did you verify that calloc() did not return NULL?

Comment: `sz` should be declared as type `size_t` (see `man calloc` and `man fread`). As a debug check, you could print `sz` to make sure it is what you think it should be in value.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` and friends, in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: Thoughts?, Sure: Check your api results before assuming they worked. You have six of them in the posted code, and exactly *zero* of them are validated before assuming their success.

Comment: @unwind I now never cast the result of `malloc` in `C` :) Also this is a pretty funny and interesting read. http://users.powernet.co.uk/eton/c/hackerhotel.html

Comment: @ajay Great to hear it. And yeah, that's a great story. :)